# Dart, Only static members can be accessed in initializers in simple class example

Tags: dart

In this code below,

```
class SimpleClass {
  final String ID;

  BusInformationScreen({this.ID});

  var output = ID;
}
```

I got an error 
`Only static members can be accessed in initializers.`

so i adjusted code like this below.

```
class SimpleClass {
  static final String ID;

  var output = ID;
}
```

I thought if i declare `ID` as a `static`, It doesn't have to initialize it but i got an error like this.

```
The final variable 'ID' must be initialized.
```

What is the reason that i couldn't declare variable `output`?

---

```
class SimpleClass {
  final String ID;
  final String output;
  SimpleClass_2 simpleclass_2 = SimpleClass_2(parameter: ID), SimpleClass_2 simpleclass_2 = SimpleClass_2(parameter: ID);

  SimpleClass({this.ID}): output = ID;
}

class SimpleClass_2 {
  final parameter;

  SimpleClass_2({
    this.parameter
  });
}
```

Comment: Is `BusInformationScreen` supposed to be the constructor for the class? If so, it needs to have the same name as the class. Or at least the same name followed by `.` and then a different name

Comment: @olevegard can you see the code i just added? I am trying to create a instance of ```SimpleClass_2``` and use ```ID``` as a parameter but i got a same error this time also. What is the reason?

Comment: What are you trying to do here : 
` SimpleClass_2 simpleclass_2 = SimpleClass_2(parameter: ID), SimpleClass_2 simpleclass_2 = SimpleClass_2(parameter: ID);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm gonna assume `BusInformationScreen` is supposed to be the constructor for `SimpleClass` )

The problem is

```
var output = ID;
```

You're trying to set the value for `output` before the class has been constructed. You can set it in the initializer list instead :

```
  SimpleClass({this.ID}):
        output= ID;
```