# Dart, error: Only static members can be accessed in initializers when use class instance

Tags: dart

```
class BusInformationScreen {
  final nodeId;

  BusInformationScreen({this.nodeId}); // initialize

  GetAPI getAPI = GetAPI(nodeID: nodeId);
  var busInfoList =   getAPI
}

class GetAPI {
  final nodeID;

  GetAPI({
    this.nodeID
  });

  // Let's say this class returns a list called lst
}
```

class `GetAPI` has a parameter `nodeID`

I'd like to use `GetAPI` in `BusInformationScreen` class.

First, i made an instance of `GetAPI` which is named `getAPI` and i got a `nodeId` as a parameter of `nodeID`.

Second, getAPI will gives a `lst` and i want to save lst to `busInfoList` variable.

But i got `Only static members can be accessed in initializers`
because of `nodeId` and `getAPI`.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you understand the problem and the solution in [your earlier version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019601/dart-only-static-members-can-be-accessed-in-initializers-in-simple-class-exampl)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize GetAPI from inside your constructor:

```
class BusInformationScreen {
  final nodeId;
  var busInfoList;

  BusInformationScreen({this.nodeId}) {
    GetAPI getAPI = GetAPI(nodeID: nodeId);
    busInfoList = getAPI;
  }
}
```